# usa date format to europe

Tags: excel, vba, date, date-format, excel-dates

i have problem, that this macro is searching date with format mm/dd/yyyy and i need this format dd/mm/yyyy. Please help me to fix it

There is my code

```
 n = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
 If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & (n- 4), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & (n)
Else
If Weekday(Now()) = vbTuesday Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & (n- 4), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & (n)        
Else
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & (n- 2), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & (n)
```

Comment: VBA does not care about the date format. You must be sure that `Criteria1` is a long resulted from a `Date`. Please, try using `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & clng(Date) - 4, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & clng(Date)`. And use the second parameter to be sure that the correct week day is returned: `Weekday(Now(), vbMonday)` or whatever first day you like to consider, if it is not the English default...

Comment: thanks its working

Comment: Glad I could help!